# Android formatting phone number both international or local

Tags: android

I would like to convert my phone number to meet international or local format. But using PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber() using default local format type. cannot give the desired result.

> formattingType =
>   PhoneNumberUtils.getFormatTypeForLocale(Locale.getDefault());
>   PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(editable, formattingType);

for example:

```
input         -> expected result    -> actual result    
0212345678     -> 02 1234 5678      -> 021-234-5678
0912345678     -> 0912 345 678      -> 091-234-5678
+886912345678  -> +886 912 345 678  -> +886912345678
+18055673802   -> +1 805-567-3802   -> +18055673802
```

The expected result is referenced from Native dialer call log.

Can any one give some suggestion, how to get the expected result according to the country code and local number.

Comment: `PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber` has many overload, which one are you using? I think you should always provide the country code.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#formatNumber(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: And which formatted are you using? You can also get the format type from the locale. I think that's almost always the best option.

Comment: Use it like this: formatNumber(number, getFormatTypeFromLocale(locale));

Comment: @jobbert , i think i use the same as you suggested. But the locale i think is US. But the same device, native dialer call log is the expected one. I think it is using different way to format phone number.

Comment: What is your device? Have you tested it on multiple devices?

Comment: @jobbert, yeah, different devices have different result depending on the locale.

Comment: @user3733534, sorry let me rephrase that: Have you tested it with multiple devices with the same locale, but different dialers. And what is your main test device?

Comment: Have you tried other solutions like: http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber/5.8 ?

Comment: not yet. Due to some consideration, i currently no need to do this. If i need it in future, i will take a try. Thank you

Comment: Before proceeding, read this "Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Phone Numbers" https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md